# Rendering <NuxtImg> in @nuxt/content (v2) markdown file with Nuxt v3

Tags: nuxtjs3

In the previous version of @nuxt/content (1.x) with Nuxt v2 and @nuxt/img (v0), you used to be able to write this in your Markdown files:

`content/example.md`

```markdown
<nuxt-img src="img/myImage.jpg"></nuxt-img>
```

In Nuxt v3 world, with the latest @nuxt/content (2.2.1) and @nuxt/image-edge (1.0.0-27769790.4b27db3), I am getting this error while running in development (`yarn run dev`):

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: NuxtImg
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to use the new MDC syntax? Is it not yet supported, or not supported when SSR is disabled (`ssr: false`)?

There's a few tickets I'm aware of/watching:

- @nuxt/image Checklist for Nuxt 3 support: https://github.com/nuxt/image/discussions/548
- @nuxt/image feat: support prerendering static images: https://github.com/nuxt/image/pull/614
- @nuxt/content Support for @nuxt/image (v1): https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/624

**Details**

`package.json`

```json
"@nuxt/content": "^2.2.1",
"@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-27769790.4b27db3",
"nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.13"
```

NOTE: `@nuxt/image-edge` is the work-in-progress for the new `@nuxt/image` v1 module which will work with Nuxt 3. Mentioned [here](https://github.com/nuxt/image/discussions/548).

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false, // Use without SSR
  components: false // Disabled auto-import components
})
```

Comment: Not sure but you maybe need to import the image module into the `modules` key?

Comment: @kissu Yep, I have it like in the [docs](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/get-started):
`export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxt/image-edge',
  ]
})`

Comment: @kissu Actually I'm getting the same error on another page where the .md file has a `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` in it... so it seems like the default Nuxt 3 components are not accessible from the @nuxt/content context yet?

Comment: I'll also ask about the correct way to use components in @nuxt/content (v2) here: https://github.com/nuxt/content/discussions/1663

Answer (score 1):

nuxt: v3.1.2
@nuxt/content: v2.4.2
@nuxt/image-edge: 1.0.0-27913696.5d122a3

---

Solution:
create the file `components/content/ProseImg.vue` with following content:

```js
<template>
  <nuxt-img v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
```

Usage `file.md`:

```
![Captain Jack Sparrow](/images/jack.png){height="800", quality="80", preload}
```

Reference: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/390#issuecomment-1344593577

Comment: This is the workaround I ended up going with 